# BASH MySQL output to dynamic variables

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I'm using the following BASH mysql statement to get data from my DB.

```
mysql -N -u root --password=ROOT DB -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT * FROM site where id like '1234'" | while read A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z; do
    echo $A
    echo $B
done
```

To get all the values for A to Z this seems a long winded way.

How can I do this better and create variables based on the `read` value name and results. ?

eg:
`create var A which contains value of $A and do this all the way upto var Z containing the value of $Z`

This is only an example, the values won't be called A-Z, but have proper names. Is there any way to create variable based on the true proper name and then associate the value to it ?

eg:

`mysql -N -u root --password=ROOT DB -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT * FROM site where id like '1234'" | while read site_id site_location site_size etc.......`; do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` call needs to be piped-in to the while loop this way:

```sh
while read -r site_id site_location site_size _ ; do
  echo "$site_id" "$site_location" "$site_size"
done < <(
  mysql -N -u root --password=ROOT DB -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT * FROM site where id like '1234'"
)
```

The `< <(command)` redirection allows the `command` to execute in a sub-shell, but feed the main thread's `read`. So when it `read -r var1 var2 ... varn < <(command)`, variables are valid for the main thread.

Whereas `command | read -r var` has `command` to execute in the main thread and `read` execute in a sub-shell, and var is only valid within the sub-shell.

#### Getting variable names matching each column name from the table

This script reads the table description and creates a `vars` array containing the column names.

It reads, creates and prints each shell variable of these names using indirection.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Pupulate the vars array with the column names from the table
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a vars < <(
  mysql -N -u root --password=ROOT DB -h 127.0.0.1 -e 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM site' |
    cut -d ' ' -f1
)

# Output column headers
printf '%s\t' "${vars[@]}"

# read and create variables names matching column names
while read -r "${vars[@]}"; do
  for varname in "${vars[@]}"; do
    # Use ! indirection to print the value for the variable
    printf '%s\t' "${!varname}"
  done
done < <(
  mysql -N -u root --password=ROOT DB -h 127.0.0.1 -e "SELECT * FROM site where id like '1234'"
)
```